# How to generate different random numbers in a for loop with C

Tags: c, random

How to choose the distinct initial seeds to generate different random numbers in [0,1] in a for loop with C?

Comment: sounds like homework.

Answer (score 2):

Vague answer to a vague question :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(){
    int i;

    srand(time(NULL));

    for(i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        printf("%i ", rand()%2);
    }

    return 0;
}
```